# Why is my QML textArea not appending?

Tags: c++, qt, text, append, qml

I am trying to write some Qt C++ code that interacts with QML objects. The goal is to have strings received on a TCP socket appended to a text log on the GUI. Each time a new string is received, I run the appendText() function. I have one implementation of this currently working that uses QWidgets and a .ui file. I need to have a QML implementation that is identical. My QWidget implementation uses a textBrowser and the append function such as the following. "theString" is changing as the program runs and each change is appended, filling up the text log.

```
//update the text log with data received on TCP socket
void MainWindow::appendText() {
    ui->textBrowser->append(theString);

}
```

This gives me the desired result, appending each string to the text box as they come in. The output should look like the following.

```
Control connection successful.
Data connection successful.
Control Packet Receieved: 
1
Control Packet Receieved: 
2
Control Packet Receieved: 
3
Control Packet Receieved: 
4
Control Packet Receieved: 
1
Control Packet Receieved: 
2
Control Packet Receieved: 
3
Control Packet Receieved: 
4
```

However, when doing what I believe to be the same function with a QML object with the following code...

```
//update the text log with data received on TCP socket
void MainWindow::appendText() {
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(textbox, "append", Qt::DirectConnection, Q_ARG(QVariant, theString));
    //QQmlProperty(textbox, "text").write(theString);

}
```

It only appends the first two strings, and no more beyond that. The output looks like this instead.

```
Control connection successful.
Data connection successful.
```

I have looked over the documentation for invoking QML methods in C++ extensively and still haven't had any luck. Any help is appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce your problem.

**Possible solution**

It may be a solution to use `import QtQuick.Controls 2.0`.

In that case, I obtain the following error message:

> ```
> QMetaObject::invokeMethod: No such method QQuickTextArea::append(QVariant)
> Candidates are:
>     append(QString)
> ```

As suggested by the error message, you should use `QString` now instead of `QVariant` as parameter type:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(textbox, "append", Qt::DirectConnection, Q_ARG(QString, theString));
```

**Better alternative**

As mentioned by Qt, you should [avoid manipulating QML object from C++](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html) (deep into the object tree):

> **Warning:** While it is possible to use C++ to access and manipulate QML objects deep into the object tree, we recommend that you do not
>   take this approach outside of application testing and prototyping. One
>   strength of QML and C++ integration is the ability to implement the
>   QML user interface separately from the C++ logic and dataset backend,
>   and this strategy breaks if the C++ side reaches deep into the QML
>   components to manipulate them directly.

Therefore, it may be a better alternative to implement a signal in C++ which emit the newly received messages and connect to it from the QML side. This approach clearly separates user interface and programming logic.

**Working example code**

The following code appends `"test"` to the `TextArea` every second.

main.cpp:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QQuickItem>

QObject *textbox;

void onTimeout()
{
  QMetaObject::invokeMethod(textbox, "append", Qt::DirectConnection, Q_ARG(QVariant, "test"));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

  QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
  engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

  QTimer t;
  QObject::connect(&t, &QTimer::timeout, &onTimeout);
  textbox = engine.rootObjects().first()->children().first();

  t.start(1000);

  return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

Window
{
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 600

    TextArea
    {
        id: textbox
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I try the fix using QString I receive this error:
QMetaObject::invokeMethod: No such method TextArea_QMLTYPE_31::append(QString)
Candidates are:
    append(QVariant)...

I'm fairly certain the first two messages are not printed by any other method because the appendText() function I have is the only one where I actually write anything to the GUI. I will try a signal based approach in the meantime.

Comment: Which Qt/QML version are you using? Are you using the builtin `TextArea`? How do you obtain `textbox` in C++? Are you sure `MainWindow::appendText` is called correctly?

Comment: I am using Qt Creator 4.2.1. I am using a TextArea object in my QML file. The TextArea object is the child of a groupBox object. I obtain textbox by doing this line:     textbox = groupBox2->findChild<QObject*>("networkStatus");.....
Also I am using QMetaObject:invokeMethod, where there is a method called append for TextArea objects

Comment: Importing the QtQuick.controls 2.1 fixed it! Thank you.